# facebook like button for redirecting site

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have special offerings gallery site (lets say example.com) and each offering has a "Like" button. "Like" button has example.com/45 url which directs original offering site (lets say superoffer.com). The problem is that my like button shows superoffer.com "likes" and not my redirect url likes. How can i pass this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Facebook does not allow you to create likes for pages that do redirects. You should make example.com/45 a landing page that links the user to the destination page. This way Facebook will send the user to your site, then the user can click a link to go to the next site.